# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in cv::calibrateCamera

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am having some problems using the "calibrationCamera" method from openCV. I am running OpenCV in Windows 64, visual studio 2013.

The problem comes when I call the following function: "cv::calibrateCamera" from OpenCV,  it throws the exception "Assertion failed (nimages > 0)".

Here's a sample of the code developed:

```
vector< vector< Vec3f > > _object_points;
vector< vector< Vec2f > > _image_points;

_hor_corners = 9;
_ver_corners = 6;
_squareSize = 20; // Let's say 20 mm

_patternsize = Size(_hor_corners, _ver_corners);

Mat corners; 
vector<Vec2f> imgP;
vector< Vec3f > obj;

for (int i = 0; i < _ver_corners; i++) //Create the 3d vector
    for (int j = 0; j < _hor_corners; j++)
        obj.push_back(Point3f((float)j * _squareSize, (float)i * _squareSize, 0));

for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
{
    image = calibImages[i];

    // ... code for detecting corners


    if (corners.rows == _hor_corners*_ver_corners)
    {
        _image_points.push_back(imgP); //fill arrays
        _object_points.push_back(obj);
        cout << imgP.size() << "___" << _image_points.size() << "___" << obj.size() << "___" << _object_points.size() << endl; //here's everything is okay

        imgP.clear();


    }
}
cv::calibrateCamera(_object_points, _image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, 0); //Throw the exception here
```

And here where is assertion is being thrown:

```
double cv::calibrateCamera( InputArrayOfArrays _objectPoints,
                        InputArrayOfArrays _imagePoints,
                        Size imageSize, InputOutputArray _cameraMatrix, InputOutputArray _distCoeffs,
                        OutputArrayOfArrays _rvecs, OutputArrayOfArrays _tvecs, int flags, TermCriteria criteria ){
    int rtype = CV_64F;
    Mat cameraMatrix = _cameraMatrix.getMat();
    cameraMatrix = prepareCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, rtype);
    Mat distCoeffs = _distCoeffs.getMat();
    distCoeffs = prepareDistCoeffs(distCoeffs, rtype);
    if( !(flags & CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL) &&
    (!(flags & CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL)) &&
    (!(flags & CALIB_TILTED_MODEL)))
        distCoeffs = distCoeffs.rows == 1 ? distCoeffs.colRange(0, 5) : distCoeffs.rowRange(0, 5);

    int nimages = int(_objectPoints.total());
    CV_Assert( nimages > 0 );
    Mat objPt, imgPt, npoints, rvecM, tvecM;
```

I did some searching around the internet but couldn't find any possible logical answer for this problem. The vectors are being filled correctly and have the same length. Any idea of what may be happening here?

Thank you very much,

Comment: It is good if you show more details of the input you are passing... but my guess is that you pass a Vector of points instead of a Vector of Vector of points? Can you pass how you create objectPoints and how it is passed to the function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Find above a sample of the code developed.